# subsurf splits the mirrored model into two objects

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I tried to subsurf this model that I mirrored but when I use subsurf it splits the model into two objects.

Before Subsurf:
[image]

After Subsurf:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things could be effecting your model.

- Internal faces cause the subsurf modifier to "pull in". To fix this you need to delete the faces that will become internal faces after the mirror modifier duplicates your mesh.

[image: Example of removing faces]

- The order that the modifiers are listed effects how they interact. Having the subsurf before the mirror can cause the edges in the centre of the mesh to pull away before the mirror duplicates the mesh. To fix this you need to have the subsurf under the mirror modifier. You can use the up and down arrows on the modifiers to re-order them.
- If your subsurf modifier is after the mirror and the edges still shrink away from the centre of your object you need to enable merge in the mirror modifier. Enabling clipping in the mirror modifier can also help to get the centre vertices aligned so that they merge.

Comment: yes. this might be it. I have a face on the inside I will delete when I am done at work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the mirror modifier check the clipping box so that the intersection in the middle doesn't split if you haven't already applied the mirror modifier

Comment: Even when I have clipping turned on it doesn't connect when I apply the mirror modifier. Before I add subsurf I have to manually move the mirrored side to be aligned properly.

Answer (score 0):

From what your screen shot shows, these are my suggestions : Make sure that *'clipping'* is turned on for the mirror modifier on the `y axis`, then  add *smooth shading* to the model, and *apply* the mirror modifier. Then add a *subsurf* modifier. *Apply* the subsurf modifier, and all should look good.

Comment: the advice to set _smooth shading_ + _apply modifier_ aren't vital to showing the OP what the problem is here.

Comment: Even when I have clipping turned on it doesn't connect when I apply the mirror modifier. Before I add subsurf I have to manually move the mirrored side to be aligned properly.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen sometimes, as the modifiers are switched,

The Mirror Modifier has to be on top of the SUBD modifier so the mesh can merge together before getting distorted by the smoothing of the SUBD.

**Solution:
Mirror Modifier over SUBD Modifier.**

[image]

[image]